# LANZAR DISPARADOR CADA VEZ QUE SE ACTUALICE EL SALARIO

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, trigger, plsql

Hola gente estoy intentando lanzar un disparador cada vez que se actualice el salario del empleado, el disparador comprueba si la antigüedad del empleado es mayor a 10 se le suma un 20% el salario y si es mayor a 15 se le suma un 40%, hice algo parecido pero me da fallos, así que no entiendo ni sé como se hace, agradecería vuestra ayuda

Aquí les dejo el código que tengo hecho:

```
create or replace trigger AUMENTAR_SALARIO_SEGUN_ANTIGUEDAD

AFTER UPDATE
ON SALARIO_EMPLEADO_JJ
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE SALARIO_EMPLEADO_JJ 
  SET SALARIO = CASE antiguedad
    WHEN (ANTIGUEdad>4)AND ( antiguedad<11) THEN :new.salario:=:old.salario*1.2;
    WHEN (ANTIGUEdad>9 AND antiguedad<16) THEN :new.salario:=:old.salario*1.5;
  END CASE;
END
```

Intente hacer una condición al actualizar el salario pero sin resultado

Comment: "hice algo parecido pero me da fallos" que fallos?

Answer (score 0):

Y no sería mas sencillo con IF

```sql
IF :new.antiguedad > 4 AND :new.antiguedad < 11 THEN
    :new.salario := :old.salario * 1.2;
ELSIF :new.antiguedad > 9 AND :new.antiguedad < 16 THEN
    :new.salario := :old.salario * 1.5;
END IF;
```

Comment: Antes de nada muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me da fallos de error de sintaxis create or replace trigger AUMENTAR_SALARIO_SEGUN_ANTIGUEDAD

AFTER UPDATE
ON SALARIO_EMPLEADO_JJ
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE SALARIO_EMPLEADO_JJ 
    SET SALARIO = IF :new.antiguedad > 4 AND :new.antiguedad < 11 THEN
    :new.salario := :old.salario * 1.2;
        ELSIF :new.antiguedad > 9 AND :new.antiguedad < 16 THEN
            :new.salario := :old.salario * 1.5;
        END IF;
END;

Comment: Que raro, pero es Oracle verdad ?

Comment: el trigger debe ser BEFORE UPDATE